# java linkedNode implementation

Tags: java, nodes

I am trying to implement the boolean method taking a parameter of ListNode list then the method will return true if the list meets null. If the nodes point back to the previous node then it should return false.
 For example, 1, 2, 3, null --> true 1 , 2, 3, (points back to previous node) 2, 3, 2, 3, etc. The below static method is the one I made, but when I try to prove whether the method works correctly, it does not work that way I thought. I attached my code below.

```
class ListNode<T> {
public T value;
public ListNode<T> next;

public ListNode(T value, ListNode<T> next)
{
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

public ListNode<T> setValue(T value) 
{
    return new ListNode<T>(value, this); 
}
}




 class Test
```

{

public static  boolean terminates(ListNode list) 
    {

```
    if(list == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    ListNode slow;
    ListNode fast;

    slow = list;
    fast = list;

    while(true)
    {
        slow = slow.next; 

        if(fast.next != null) 
        {
            fast = fast.next.next;   
        }
        else 
        {
            return true; // next node is null 
        }


        if(slow == null || fast == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(slow == fast)
        {
            return false; 
        }
```

}

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    ListNode list3; // header3
    ListNode one3 = null;
    ListNode two3 = null;
    ListNode three3 = new ListNode(3, two3);

    one3 = new ListNode(1, two3);
    two3 = new ListNode(2, three3);

    list3 = one3;
    System.out.println(terminates(list3));//IT SHOULD RETURN FALSE, BUT IT DOES NOT

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Objects.isNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) instead of the '== null' you have throughout your code.